# Query and formula to form entire table, with new column, where new column is a formula involving other conditional column values

Tags: mysql, sql

EDIT: **the formula should be the 'value' column - the 'value' column with the lowest user_id based on category.**

**So row 2 would be 0.04, since the 'value' column of the lowest 'user_id' for category 'A' is 0.01.**

Sorry about that.

I would like to retrieve everything from a table, with another column added, that involves a formula with info based on other columns. Here is the original table:

| category | user_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0.01 |
| A | 2 | 0.05 |
| B | 4 | 0.34 |
| B | 7 | 0.27 |

<s>**The new column has to be the 'value' column, minus the lowest value 'user_id' for the 'category', for each row**. So for the second row, it would be (0.05 - 1), since the category is 'A', and the lowest 'user_id' for 'A' is 1.</s>

There are far more rows and columns, this is just an example.

What formula would I use?

Here is what I have so far, just to be able to show that I am able to create the new column, but without the correct formula:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table 
 AS (select * FROM table_1);
 
 ALTER TABLE new_table
 ADD COLUMN `new_column` DECIMAL(3,2)
 GENERATED ALWAYS AS (table_1.value-table_1.value) STORED;
 
 select * from new_table;
```

This obviously gives me the new column, but with 0 (since it subtracts itself).

What is the correct formula?

Here is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
  `category` VARCHAR(2),
  `user_id` INT(2), 
  `value` DECIMAL(3,2)
 );
INSERT INTO table_1
(`category`, `user_id`, `value`)
VALUES
('A', 1, 0.01),
('A', 2, 0.05),
('B', 4, 0.34),
('B', 7, 0.27)
;
```

Comment: i'm not a mysql expert but a generated columns can only refer to columns in the same row; you need to create a *view*.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you for that. So essentially replace the ALTER TABLE/ADD COLUMN with CREATE VIEW? Do you happen to know what I'd input for this formula in that situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql> create view new_table as 
  select category, user_id, value, 
    value - min(user_id) over (partition by category) as adjusted_value
  from table_1;

mysql> select * from new_table;
+----------+---------+-------+----------------+
| category | user_id | value | adjusted_value |
+----------+---------+-------+----------------+
| A        |       1 |  0.01 |          -0.99 |
| A        |       2 |  0.05 |          -0.95 |
| B        |       4 |  0.34 |          -3.66 |
| B        |       7 |  0.27 |          -3.73 |
+----------+---------+-------+----------------+
```

This uses a [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), which means it requires MySQL 8.0, which is the current version of MySQL since 2018.

---

Re your comment: using the `value` column from the lowest user_id in the category:

```
mysql> create or replace view new_table as 
  select category, user_id, value, 
    value - first_value(value) over (partition by category order by user_id) as adjusted_value  
  from table_1;

mysql> select * from new_table;
+----------+---------+-------+----------------+
| category | user_id | value | adjusted_value |
+----------+---------+-------+----------------+
| A        |       1 |  0.01 |           0.00 |
| A        |       2 |  0.05 |           0.04 |
| B        |       4 |  0.34 |           0.00 |
| B        |       7 |  0.27 |          -0.07 |
+----------+---------+-------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful.
How would you make it to be the value column minus the value column for the lowest user_id in each category?

Comment: Both of your answers worked perfectly for both values. Thank you so much! Do you have any learning resources or recommendations for SQL? I can do simple things, but this level of complexity had me lost for quite a while, and I searched for hours before finally asking this.

Comment: My method isn't the fastest. I just practice a lot, and spend a lot of time answering questions online on sites like this. Answering other people's questions is a great way to learn. You get shown problems you may never have encountered on your own, and your answers must be right or else the person with the question will come back and ask you to fix it. :-) Teaching a topic to someone else is always the best way to cement your own understanding, in any subject.

Answer (score 0):

Inb mysql 5.7 you can use a subquery for the purpose, the view seems top be a better coice than a new table, but as the selects are eqal, you can choose

> ```
> Create view new_tableview as
> SELECT t1.`category`, t1.`user_id`, t1.`value`, t2.minid - t1.`value` as new_value FROM table_1 t1 JOIN 
> ( SELECT `category`,MIN(`user_id`) minid FROM table_1 GROUP BY `category`) t2 ON t1.`category` = t2.`category`
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM new_tableview
> ```
>
> ```
> category | user_id | value | new_value
> :------- | ------: | ----: | --------:
> A        |       1 |  0.01 |      0.99
> A        |       2 |  0.05 |      0.95
> B        |       4 |  0.34 |      3.66
> B        |       7 |  0.27 |      3.73
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9776aa7ff1936e5488823886fcf8b5ab)*